# Error Handling in Web Design

Tags: exception, error-handling

I'm thinking about some optimal methods for gracefully handling errors on a website. I'm thinking that two modes will dictate how errors are handled:

**Development Mode**

- Shows all notices, warning, and fatal errors on the view they are generated from
- Errors are displayed in raw format

**Production Mode**

- Hide all notices and warnings, no matter what
- Redirect fatal errors to a page (something like the fail whale)

  - Tell the user that the error has been logged
  - Store information about the error in the database or some other type of log (developer's choice)
  - E-mail the error to an array of e-mail addresses (developer's choice)

What are your thoughts on this approach? Can you think of a better way to handle errors?

Answer (score 1):

Production mode - instead of emailing developers and storing the error to databases yourself. Integrate with defect/bug tracking system like [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/), let it handle all the emailing, assignments, etc... No need to reinvent the wheel. Integration is simple, just use [Bugzilla web services](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html).

Answer (score 0):

For production I highly recommend using a error logging service like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) or [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/). They have free plans that should cover most of personal or small business websites.

Why use these services? They offer a simple script or one line of code you add to your website or app and the service will handle error logging, storage and notifications. For example, if a users uses a broken function, the logging service will record the error, send it to their servers, analyze it, store it and send you a notification like `PROJECT1 - TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName.ToString is not a function` to you.
Also, they provide their implementations for several languages so you could log your PHP backend and your JS frontend at the same time.

Using a specialized service will save you a lot of time. No need to write your own API, storage for errors and configure some push or notification service. I use Sentry for several months now and I'm very happy with it. It's basically a "setup once and forget"-thing.